# Plain JavaScript Custom Validation Run Validation on keyup

Tags: javascript

I wrote a custom JavaScript validator that needs  to run on every keyup event that is attached to ever input and runs the vacillator() for every  input field.

Problem is that it only works on load.
I want to to work on every key-up event. 
Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/717/

```
function display_error(elem, message) {
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<label class='js-error' style='color:red;' >" + message + "</label>");
}

function check_error(elem) {
    error_label = elem.nextElementSibling
    if (error_label && error_label.classList.contains('js-error')) {
        return true;
    }


}

function add_error(elem,message) {
    if (!check_error(elem)){
        display_error(elem, message)

    }

}

function delete_error(elem) {
    if (check_error(elem)){
        elem.nextElementSibling.remove();      

    }

}

function validateForm(elem) {
alert("Checking if form is vaild")

    // If input type == text
    if (elem.getAttribute("type") == 'text') {
        //alert("elemcent is text")

        maxlength = elem.getAttribute("maxlength")
        minlength = elem.getAttribute("minlength")
        data_error = elem.getAttribute("data-error")


        // if has attribute maxlegnth
        if (minlength) {
            // if value is under min length
            if (elem.value.length < parseInt(minlength)) {
                // add errors
                add_error(elem, data_error)
                //alert("above min length")

            } else {
                // Delete
                //alert("delere errror")
                delete_error(elem)

            }
        }


        }

        // if input type == number
            if (elem.getAttribute("type") == 'number') {
        //alert("element is text")

        max = elem.getAttribute("max")
        min = elem.getAttribute("min")
        data_error = elem.getAttribute("data-error")


        // if has attribute maxlegnth
        if (min) {
            // if value is under min length
            if (elem.value < parseInt(min)) {
                // add errors
                add_error(elem, data_error)
                //alert("Belove Min Number")
            }
            else if(elem.value > parseInt(max)){


                // add errors
                add_error(elem, data_error)
                //alert("above Max number")
            }
            else {
                // Delete
                //alert("delere errror")
                delete_error(elem)

            }
        }


        }



}

// Desired Result
// if keyup
    // for input in inputs:
        // someFunc(input) that makes input tags red
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');

for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    elem = inputs[i]
  elem.addEventListener('keyup', validateForm(elem))

}
```

Comment: `validateForm(elem)` is a function call.

Comment: How whould i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your event handler straight away. It needs to be wrapped with a function. So this:

```
elem.addEventListener('keyup', validateForm(elem))
```

should be:

```
elem.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    // do something with event
    validateForm(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I replaced it with this and it works but it only runs the vaildator for the current input on keypress. I want it to run the validates for all inputs when key is pressed